# Attempting to Log into Amazon using Python

Tags: authentication

This is the code that I am using to try and log into amazon. Every time, I run it, it returns the message that the login failed, even when all the login info is correct. It can't be a mistype because I have checked many times so the login info that I entered is correct. Does anyone have a solution?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

site = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html'

session = requests.Session()

'''define session headers'''
session.headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.61 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': site
}

'''get login page'''
resp = session.get(site)
html = resp.text

'''get BeautifulSoup object of the html of the login page'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

'''scrape login page to get all the needed inputs required for login'''
data = {}
form = soup.find('form', {'name': 'signIn'})
for field in form.find_all('input'):
    try:
        data[field['name']] = field['value']
    except:
        pass
data[u'email'] = 'Enter_Username'
data[u'password'] = 'Enter_Password'

post_resp = session.post('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin', data = data)

post_soup = BeautifulSoup(post_resp.content, 'lxml')

if post_soup.find_all('title')[0].text == 'Your Account':
    print('Login Successfull')
else:
    print('Login Failed')


session.close()
```

Comment: I found that updating the user agent to a more recent one actually helped.  Also the referrer, if you can set it to an actual page you fail to login to, seems to make it work more reliably.